# CSS Long font problem that does not fit the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I encode chat with HTML + CSS. But I'm probably having a problem with **CSS flex**.

The problem is that when you write a very long message, the inbox on the left becomes narrow. There are no problems with the text message. Is there any way you can help me with this?

**Problem Images:**
[image]

**Normal Layout: (Requested):**
[image]

```html
<link href="https://userstar.app/code/css/style.css?v=1" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://userstar.app/code/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="chat-container">
    <!-- Gelen Mesajlar -->
    <div id="chat-bar">
        <div style="padding: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text" style=" background: transparent; "><i class=" material-icons-outlined"> search </i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="message-list-container">
            <ul>

                <li id="item-message" data-message="1">
                    <div class="user-avatar-container"><img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/43A3/production/_103051371_hannahmackenzie.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="message-text-container">
                        <div class="user-name-container">
                            <div class="name">Ceren Aksoy</div>
                            <div class="time">17 Eyl</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-message-container">
                            <span>A İlanı</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li id="item-message" data-message="3">
                    <div class="user-avatar-container"><img src="http://localhost/assets/images/no-avatar.svg"></div>
                    <div class="message-text-container">
                        <div class="user-name-container">
                            <div class="name">Huseyin Ozer</div>
                            <div class="time">17 Eyl</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-message-container">
                            <span>B İlanı</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Mesajlaşma -->
    <div id="chat-window">
        <div class="chat-window-header">
            <span class="chat-user-info">
 <div class="chat-user-avatar"><img id="__ajaxUserPhoto" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/43A3/production/_103051371_hannahmackenzie.jpg"></div>
 <div id="__ajaxUserFullName">Ceren Aksoy</div>
</span>

        </div>

        <div class="message-box">
            <div class="chat-subject"><a id="__ajaxChatSubject" href="">A İlanı</a> ilanı hakkında konuşuyorsunuz.</div>

            <div class="message-content-container">
                <div class="message-content">
                    <div class="item-row you">
                        <div class="message">
                            <div class="message-container">
                                <div class="message-box"><span class="selectable-text">Hello Ceren!</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-row me arrow">
                        <div class="message">
                            <div class="message-container">
                                <div class="message-box"><span class="selectable-text">Hi Alex</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-row you arrow">
                        <div class="message">
                            <div class="message-container">
                                <div class="message-box"><span class="selectable-text">What Are you doing ? </span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-row you">
                        <div class="message">
                            <div class="message-container">
                                <div class="message-box"><span class="selectable-text">:) </span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-row me arrow">
                        <div class="message">
                            <div class="message-container">
                                <div class="message-box"><span class="selectable-text">When writing too long, the sidebar narrows. I'm looking for a solution. I have problems with CSS. Help.  Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please.</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="message-form">
                    <textarea name="message" maxlength="500" rows="1" placeholder="Bir mesaj yaz..."></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why not set a min width on the message-list container?

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach The problem is not solved. I've tried. And still trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to `#chat-bar` `flex-shrink:0` and it will solve.

```css
#chat-bar{
  flex-shrink:0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://userstar.app/code/css/style.css?v=1" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://userstar.app/code/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="chat-container">
    <!-- Gelen Mesajlar -->
    <div id="chat-bar">
        <div style="padding: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text" style=" background: transparent; "><i class=" material-icons-outlined"> search </i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="message-list-container">
            <ul>

                <li id="item-message" data-message="1">
                    <div class="user-avatar-container"><img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/43A3/production/_103051371_hannahmackenzie.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="message-text-container">
                        <div class="user-name-container">
                            <div class="name">Ceren Aksoy</div>
                            <div class="time">17 Eyl</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-message-container">
                            <span>A İlanı</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li id="item-message" data-message="3">
                    <div class="user-avatar-container"><img src="http://localhost/assets/images/no-avatar.svg"></div>
                    <div class="message-text-container">
                        <div class="user-name-container">
                            <div class="name">Huseyin Ozer</div>
                            <div class="time">17 Eyl</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-message-container">
                            <span>B İlanı</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Mesajlaşma -->
    <div id="chat-window">
        <div class="chat-window-header">
            <span class="chat-user-info">
 <div class="chat-user-avatar"><img id="__ajaxUserPhoto" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/43A3/production/_103051371_hannahmackenzie.jpg"></div>
 <div id="__ajaxUserFullName">Ceren Aksoy</div>
</span>

        </div>

        <div class="message-box">
            <div class="chat-subject"><a id="__ajaxChatSubject" href="">A İlanı</a> ilanı hakkında konuşuyorsunuz.</div>

            <div class="message-content-container">
                <div class="message-content">
                    <div class="item-row you">
                        <div class="message">
                            <div class="message-container">
                                <div class="message-box"><span class="selectable-text">Hello Ceren!</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-row me arrow">
                        <div class="message">
                            <div class="message-container">
                                <div class="message-box"><span class="selectable-text">Hi Alex</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-row you arrow">
                        <div class="message">
                            <div class="message-container">
                                <div class="message-box"><span class="selectable-text">What Are you doing ? </span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-row you">
                        <div class="message">
                            <div class="message-container">
                                <div class="message-box"><span class="selectable-text">:) </span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-row me arrow">
                        <div class="message">
                            <div class="message-container">
                                <div class="message-box"><span class="selectable-text">When writing too long, the sidebar narrows. I'm looking for a solution. I have problems with CSS. Help.  Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please Please.</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="message-form">
                    <textarea name="message" maxlength="500" rows="1" placeholder="Bir mesaj yaz..."></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```